# sql server field coming through as blank even though len([field]) shows characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hopefully this will be a quick one for someone.. I have an SQL Server 2012 (I think) and one of the tables is confusing me somewhat.

The column type is nvarchar(max). I have spotted a couple of records which for some reason are coming out blank in that column - even though I KNOW there is data in there. I just cannot see it!

For example, the SQL command

```
select 
    contentbody, 
    datalength(contentbody), 
    len(contentbody), 
    rtrim(contentbody) 
from 
    ContentSource 
where 
    contentid=4022
```

This shows the following results

```
contentbody = (blank)
datalength = 58
len = 57
rtrim = (blank)
```

So I can see from the len() and datalength() functions that there is something there. However I simply cannot access it. I'm seeing this problem from both our .net (4.5) website and directly from SQL Server Management Studio.

Any ideas?! I've tried cast() and convert() but it's always returning a blank. 
Thanks for any advice!

Comment: How is your len = 57 when the contentbody is blank?

Comment: Might have a `char(0)` in there. (Null character). Try casting to `binary(58)` to see what the characters are.

Comment: Casting as a binary shows this data.. ?�H�a�v�e� �i� �g�o�t� �a� �n�e�w� �l�o�v�e� �c�o�m�i�n�g�. Looks like there are some funky characters in there?!

Comment: (that's converted from Hex by the way)

Comment: Not sure how you produced that. Cast to binary and look at the hexadecimal string. Does it begin `0x00`?

Comment: The actual binary result is `0x00480061007600650020006900200067006F0074002000610020006E006500770020006C006F0076006500200063006F006D0069006E00670020`

Comment: @MattFacer - That looks like the bytes have got completely scrambled somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say in the comments that the characters are.

```
0x00480061007600650020006900200067006F0074002000610020006E006500770020006C006F0076006500200063006F006D0069006E00670020
```

This looks like it should probably be

```
0x480061007600650020006900200067006F0074002000610020006E006500770020006C006F0076006500200063006F006D0069006E006700
```

Which is

```
SELECT CAST(N'Have i got a new love coming' AS VARBINARY(100));
```

The order of every pair of bytes has been reversed from what it should be.

i.e. `0x0048` is in place of `0x4800` and so on throughout the string.

Comment: The content is added from mobile devices. It looks like someone may have used a non-ascii character? I am wondering if it's the emoticons on modern phones maybe.

Comment: @MattFacer - Actually that doesn't look like `varchar` data at all. It looks like `nvarchar`. Every other byte is `0x00`

Comment: It is a nvarchar(max) field... the characters with the 0x00 in front come out when I convert the field to a binary(58) as suggested.

Comment: @MattFacer - I edited my answer after realising it is `nvarchar`. The problem is that all the byte pairs are reversed and the content is garbage.

Comment: In the same row, I do store the ACTUAL hex value received from the user's mobile. I could write my code to say if a null value is returned from the `contentbody` field, then use the hex field. I will have to find out how I can strip and non ascii chars from the string before I save it.

Comment: @MattFacer - If you only want to allow ASCII characters then use `varchar`. But there must be something wrong with the way you are processing it for the field to contain this garbage. Are you treating it as binary at some point?

Comment: not that I know of.. it should be a simple string. In my logs, I can see it. It is bound to be when it's storing it in the nvarchar field. My worry is now changing the field type it might wreck what's already there!?

Comment: @MattFacer - Yes. Not a change that should be rushed into! Something seems to be messing up the string somewhere. Adding a leading `0x00` and trailing `0x20` possibly. Do you use `UPDATE.WRITE`?

Comment: never used update.write? It's a .net website which is adding records to the database. I have implemented a tougher ASCII regex when saving the contentbody - so for future messages that should be ok. Still need to sort out the existing ones though!! May manually do it based on the hex values... :S

Comment: @MattFacer - Well if they are all mangled in the same way `select CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(contentbody AS VARBINARY(MAX)),2,DATALENGTH(contentbody)-2) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) FROM ContentSource` should do it.

Comment: That seems to work nicely thank you - I can get read the messages now. However the messages which are ok - ie: they would be displayed normally look like chinese characters! I cannot test for a blank entry using an iif statement as there technically is something in there!

Comment: @MattFacer: Perhaps you could test if `LEFT(CAST(contentbody AS VARBINARY(MAX)), 1) = 0x00`: if true, then you need to do the conversion, otherwise you don't. So, something like this maybe: `CASE WHEN LEFT(...) = 0x00 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(...) AS nvarchar(max)) ELSE contentbody END`.

Answer (score 0):

It might contain non-printable characters.  You could try converting the result to a byte array and then look at the character codes in a debugger.